# If charge is quantised, how can It delocalize?

Tags: bond, electrons, resonance, atomic-structure

As I was trying to understand resonance, I got to know that it was imaginary phenomenon and it is just a tool to explain mechanisms and structures that are unexplained by Lewis dot structures or structures where bonds are localized.

Hence its proper description is now done using molecular orbital theory which is beyond scope of studies for new students. Now after that I got to know that delocalization of electrons releases energy or "increase stability" of system, there are two explanations on Stack Exchange:

1. One of the explanation on Stack Exchange uses "Particle in box" concept to explain the phenomenon, that is: larger the length, less is the energy.
2. The other explanation involves saying "delocalization causes charge cloud over large volume decreasing charge density, hence decreasing energy of system".

My question is: How can charge distribute over a volume if it is quantized? Does it come in discrete packets in form of electrons?

If this has any relation to probability of charge occurrence, the first explanation cannot be used, hence is there any rough, simple and intuitive explanation rather than using quantum mechanics and "Particle in box" etc.?

Comment: It is about probability of charge occurrence, like everywhere in context of orbitals and chemical bonds in quantum chemistry.

Comment: @poutnik,If it is about probability of charge occurence,hence second explaination of charge density cannot be used,so is the "particle in box" type only valid explaination here?can't it be rougly simplified ?

Comment: Review your post, namely the length of sentences,  usage of punctation and spaces. Near whole your post is one giant single sentence. As the result, it is difficult to read.

Comment: @Poutnik followed the suggestion,is it readable now?

Comment: Well, there is this concept of using dots/full stops at the end of sentences and using spaces after commas, instead of a new paragraph. Note also the general guidance that the average length of sentences in scientific texts should be 20-25 words, and the length of a particular sentence should better not exceed 35 words.

Comment: Try to apply the question in the title on a hydrogen atom. Then of HF molecule with the polar bond and partial charges of both atoms.

Comment: Hence partial charge is just a notation to describe movement of electron from its original neutral point?is it correct?@Poutnik

Comment: Electrons are **always** delocalized. The way and complexity how depends on the complexity of the system where they are delocalized. // You should really learn to write proper English sentences, if you want to communicate in English.  Long sentences, full of commas without spaces, where one forgets the beginning before reaching the end, are very hard to read.

Comment: ohh, is it something related to this explaination : in hydrogen atom, though it being neutral, at atomic scales, it is consisting of partial positive and partial negative charge which on macroscopic scale is neutral, it is not neutral like a neutron, but the net sum of charges is zero, there is still a finite distance between nucleus and electron, hence it is not intrinsically neutral as neutron

Comment: when bond forms between hydrogen and fluorine, the initial distance between electrons of hydrogen and its electron increases due to electronegativity which I suppose we call partial charge on hydrogen//sorry for poor editing skills, will try to keep that in mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148606/discussion-between-poutnik-and-dheeraj-gujrathi).

Comment: Would be good if you explain more clearly why you feel that delocalization and quantization are mutually exclusive or competing concepts. Quantization arises due to electron wavefunctions behaving as standing waves (in the time-independent case). Delocalization refers to the shape or distribution represented by that wavefunction.

Answer (score 6):

[Quantum theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) states *everything* is unlocalized until it is observed. Consider the [double-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), which applies to photons and electrons, to atoms and even molecules... Through which slit does the "particle" go? Both. What is a particle when there is no observer? A wave?

There is a *probability* of observing an electron at a location. That does not mean that the electron (or its charge) is broken into pieces, only that when it is observed, in its entirety, there is a chance that it is found *here*, or *there*.

When a photon of light goes through two slits, it does not change frequency and have half the energy go through each opening; the interference pattern is created by the probability of detecting the entire photon, at one instance, in a location.

We are distributed, all one with the universe.

Comment: I somehow didn't get the meaning of the last sentence but I would like to know. Could you please tell a bit elaborate about it...

Comment: @Proscionexium, All particles are waves. See https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/giant-molecules-exist-in-two-places-at-once-in-unprecedented-quantum-experiment/ and, just possibly, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slwkped573s